# Updating Fields in Postgres Using Angular, Node, and Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am attempting to submit a form of JSON data, utilizing angularJS, nodeJS, and JS. However, on submission the form does not capture the body data and send it to the postgres db. I know that the record is updating in the db, as I have a field "updatedAt" that changes time stamp to recent time stamp on update. I have tried grouping everything together in an updateform model, but that does not help and also hinders the displaying of data from the record on an html page. I am not sure why angular is not capturing the form data and sending it. 
Here is the html with angularJS snippet:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html > 
 <html ng-app = "todo">
 <body>
 <div class="container">
 <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
 <form ng-submit="updateTodo(updateform)" role="form" ng-init="updateform = {}">
 <div class="datagrid"><table> 
 <thead> 
 <tr> 
 <th> ID </th>
 <th> Name </th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <tr ng-repeat="todo in todos | filter:{id:todoId} | orderBy:'id' | limitTo: 1 track by $index">
 <td>
 <input type="hidden" ng-model="updateform.id" ng-init="updateform.id = todo.id">
    {{todo.id}}
 </td>
 <td>
 <div class="form-group">
 <input class="form-control" ng-model="updateform.todo" type="text"  value="{{todo.owner}}" />
 </div>
 </td>
 </tbody>
 </table>
 </div>
 <div>
  <button type="submit"><strong>Update</strong></button>
 </div>
 </form>
 </div>
 </div>
 </body>
```

From observing network, the body response is not taking any of data from the form; to which I am at a slight loss. I have tried rewriting this with different schemas, but to no avail.

Comment: question: is `$scope.updateformName` is the same as `$scope.updateform`? I think you misspelled the scope.

Comment: I intended for `$scope.updateformName` to specify the attribute of todo.name.

Comment: @fsi Do you have any suggestion? I believe problem is lying in the angular in the html

Comment: My thoughs is the bodyParser, I had this problem when I'm trying to POST something and nothing coming on the body on node server, after I added this, it worked perfectly. `var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); `

Comment: I've added your suggestion, and unfortunately that does not work either

Comment: I believe the issue is that the post method is not capturing the body response, for some reason; which I am having a tedious time finding why

Comment: well check if your req.body is getting params from your form. i usually use bodyParser for using json on body type which is work pretty fine for me.

Comment: It is not, which is issue. However, I have tried changing the format of my code -- and to no avail.